# Can Arduino Uno R3 board remove chip on the board

Tags: arduino-uno

First off, got my Elegoo Uno board as Christmas gift, so this is all new to me.

Here is my problem, I built an motor project and the chip has been programmed. Can I remove the chip from the Uno board?

Or can I placing a new chip onto the Uno board?

Best regards.

Comment: Unless you messed with the fuses you can reprogram the chip again with a new program.

Comment: The question is not clear, please edit.  What do you mean by "remove"?  I can imagine, for example, that your Uno board is one of the older versions where the atmega328 is DIP packaged.  If this is the case, then yes, you can remove the chip after programming and place on another board.

Comment: I you want to place a new chip, you have to burn the Arduino bootloader to it first. Some stores sell ATMega328Ps with bootloader already on it.

Comment: why do you want to remove the chip?

Answer (score 4):

It depends, if the chip has not been soldered, but placed in an IC (DIP) socket, than you can remove the programmed chip, and use it in another circuit and place another (same) IC in the IC socket of the Uno to be reprogrammed.

You also could desolder it, but I would not advice that; also most of the Uno's having a soldered IC use SMD instead of DIP.

Also, to replace the IC, you need to install a bootloader on the IC to be placed in the new Arduino (thanks for the addition Roberto Lo Giacco).

Below is a version with DIP that easily can be replaced, hence the big IC and the socket:

[image]

Below is a version with SMD that cannot easily be replaced, hence the small IC without a socket:

[image]

Comment: This is to me the right answer, but I would also add a note regarding the required bootloader for the new Atmega328P.

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco Thanks, I added your comment (giving you the credits).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pull the DIP chip off the board, and use it elsewhere. It will require a 16 MHz crystal and two 22pF caps (or a 16MHz resonator), at least three 0.1uF (aka 100nF) caps (connect one each from VCC, AVCC, AREF to gnd - do not connect Aref to VCC), a 10K resistor from Reset to Vcc.

If you have a  hot air rework station and decide to pull off the SMD part, that chip has two VCC pins, so another 0.1uF cap is needed.